# How to partion external HD on Ubuntu without erasing

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have an external HDD ADATA, 640GB.

I want Partitioning into two parts. The OS I am using is Ubuntu .

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to partition a drive is by using gparted

First, install gparted (`sudo apt-get install gparted`) and start it (`sudo gparted`).

Then, select your external drive from the top-right dropdown.

You can then start editing the partitions.

- If you don't need the files on the drive, erase all partitions and partition it again the way you like it.
- If you need the files and the drive is less than half full, resize the existing partition and create a new one.
- If you need the files and the drive is more than half full, move some files from the externel drive to some other external or internal drive, then resize the partition and create the second one.